# Integration testing: need test/assertion framework for testing Python SDK (not unit tests)

Tags: python, software-testing, framework, sdk

I've written an SDK for an RESTful web service. I wanted to write tests that replicate certain workflows using this API so I wrote some test scripts using Pytest. However, I'm learning the hard way, it's not written for integration tests.

For example, I am running several API calls in succession and storing the values in variables which are needed across tests. Ex: create a table => get the table id => create a record using the table id etc....

Pytest is not really designed to do that.